# Is it possible to use BreezeJS with DevForce2010?

Tags: breeze, devforce

We developed a Silverlight application some years ago that used DevForce2010.

If we would develop a web-application based on BreezeJS today, would it be possible to use the same EF-model/DevForce-server that we used in Silverlight? or would it be easier to start from scratch with a Breeze-server at the back-end?

Is there a good tutorial on how to develop a SPA/AngularJS/BreezeJS/EntityFramework application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a great tutorial on Angular + Breeze, see John Papa's two Pluralsight courses ([Part 1](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/build-apps-angular-breeze) and [Part 2](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/build-apps-angular-breeze-part2)) .

I think for the backend you'd be better off building a Web API than trying to reuse your DevForce back-end exactly "as is".  **This does not mean a re-write!** If you've written back-end DevForce code, most (if not all) will be in "save changes" interceptors. There are very similar extension points (`BeforeSaveEntities` and `AfterSaveEntities`) in the `EFContextProvider` for Breeze .NET servers; you should be able to port your code there with relative ease.

Comment: Thank you! I am going to look at those courses. I was able to copy the edmx from the old project into the new one. Then disabled "Lazy Loading Enabled" and "DevForce Enabled" - it seems to be working. This saved me a lot of time.